# Showing multiple images in one window in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why doesn't the following code show the images?

```
clear all;       
image_name = 'woman.png';
I = gray_imread(image_name);

N = 12;
J = zeros(size(I,1), size(I,2), N);
for i=1:N    
    J(:,:,i) = I;
end

sqrtt = ceil(sqrt(N));
m = sqrtt;
n = sqrtt;

for k=1:N
    K = J(:,:,k);
    subplot(m,n,k);
    imshow(K);
    set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
end
```

[image]

**How can I solve the issue?**

Comment: Is your image not empty? What is displayed by `imshow(I)`?  without `subplot` using?

Comment: @Alexander, http://i.imgur.com/NPvMuic.png

Comment: It might have to do with the ranges of your output.  use imshow(I,[0 255]) and see if that corrects the range

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf, hmm..... that worked. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your image is of `uint8` class but you're storing it in a 3-D array of `double` class. In this double class array, you have values greater than 1 which get interpreted as white.

You need to either convert your original image `I` to `double` (i.e [`I= im2double(I);`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html)) or convert `J` to [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) i.e. `J = uint8(J);`.

Comment: how was that array double? i never declared that as double.

Comment: that's the default numeric type in MATLAB.

Comment: can you elaborate that little more?

Comment: Read the documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html

Comment: Btw, it's your pre-allocation that makes it double. Not  `J(:,:,i) = I`